# Convert Cartesian Vector with a specified origin into Sperical coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I've searched everyone and I can not seem to find anything that illustrates an example of how to convert a Cartesian Vector with a specified origin into Spherical coordinates.

I know how to convert a Cartesian Vector into Spherical coordinates when the origin is 000, but I don't know what to do when it is not.

For Instance,
If given a V_(3,4,-5) with origin (3,4,5) how would I convert with the origin in mind? I know that the spherical coordinates are calculated as follow:

r=sqrt((V_x^2)+(V_y^2)+(V_z^2))

theta=inverse cos (V_z/sqrt((V_x^2)+(V_y^2)+(V_z^2)))

phi=arctan(V_y^2/V_x^2)

but then what would I do next? Any help?

Comment: I think this comes up in physics, like griffins introduction to electrodynamics. I think you always have a coordinate vector and a basis vector. In Cartesian the coordinates are the same if you translate the basis. But with spherical vectors, the coordinate changes for different basis. Maybe this has to do with charts and manifolds. Also your question while I think is good subject, is a little unclear.